# Why isn't the title attribute working on mouseover of table header?

Tags: html

I currently have a table with columns that might not immediately be obvious in meaning. How do I add mouseover explanation text to a table column header?

For example, this will add the appropriate mouseover:

```
<span title="I am hovering over the text">Test</span>
```

But when I add it to a table with:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <span title="I am hovering over the text"><th>Jill</th></span>
    <th>Smith</th>      
    <th>50</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The mouseover appears to not be applied anymore.

Comment: You can't have spans in between an opening `<tr>` and an opening `<th>`, (or `<td>`), they will be removed by the browser.

Comment: It is a nesting problem, `span` is an inline element and `th` is a table cell - working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/azizn/t6avk8fc/

Answer (score 3):

Put the `<span>` element inside the `<th>` element.

```
<th><span title="I am hovering over the text">Jill</span></th>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/80hvrfw7/

OR, simply put the `title` attribute in the `th` and get rid of the `span`.

```
<th title="I am hovering over the text">Jill</th>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/80hvrfw7/1/

Note that a table row (`<tr>`) element can only have a table cell (`<td>`) or table header (`<th>`) as child elements. By nesting a `<span>` as a child of a `<tr>` in your code you are asking the browser to render invalid HTML, which may cause unpredictable behavior.

Consider running your HTML through the W3C [Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/) to check for errors.

Answer (score 2):

Just add title attribute to table header element itself, span is not something absolutely necessary here:

```
<th title="I am hovering over the text">Jill</th>
```